# jquery ui drag & drop control

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a problem with jquery UI controls. I developed a run time form web application with bootstrap controls, but I cannot drag control anywhere. For example, how can I drag control inside tab content?

I think the problem is here that needs a change.

```
$(".sidebar-nav .box").draggable({
        connectToSortable: ".column",
        helper: "clone",
        handle: ".drag",
        drag: function (e, t) {
            t.helper.width(400)
        },
        stop: function () {
            handleJsIds()
        }
    });
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/64Agz)